# Remove characters from url

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have following `url`. Using **php** I would like to remove **/?qa=ask&cat=2/** from this `url` and replace with `/`

> http:/mysite.appspot.com/_ah/upload **/?qa=ask&cat=2/**
>   AMmfu6annb0ziCG7zXsrvLvZLzLsAh-nIitRGGfcxpcNoMTQBvsnxULJ_B5n932EDV5_jd-rllvnSfI5cqPpRUJ8FG6G17J7PHncolJ09PTu_QSLCY6JoVWc9vnmK0Pubx0Xe0OFXepcaXzXJAT1zjShFUFSfEMcCxC5yleRlo7ax2IdRVrPWHHdIqs8XvoOvmNT_7MhnOM4/ALBNUaYAAAAAUy-qo2Nb0qSl-OCR3pifnmzY7HpSBoAt

So that the new `url` looks like below:

> http:/mysite.appspot.com/_ah/upload/AMmfu6annb0ziCG7zXsrvLvZLzLsAh-nIitRGGfcxpcNoMTQBvsnxULJ_B5n932EDV5_jd-rllvnSfI5cqPpRUJ8FG6G17J7PHncolJ09PTu_QSLCY6JoVWc9vnmK0Pubx0Xe0OFXepcaXzXJAT1zjShFUFSfEMcCxC5yleRlo7ax2IdRVrPWHHdIqs8XvoOvmNT_7MhnOM4/ALBNUaYAAAAAUy-qo2Nb0qSl-OCR3pifnmzY7HpSBoAt

I guess I can use `preg_replace ($pattern,$replacement,$subject)` function where `$subject` and `$replacement` will be the original `url` and `/` character respectively.

But I can not figure out the `$pattern` expression.

Please help.

Comment: if you want to just replace a constant string (`/?qa=ask&cat=2/`) why not use [str_replace](http://www.php.net/str_replace)

Comment: Thank for the reply. "cat" parameter will vary, as in this url it is cat=2 but i could be cat=45.

Comment: I have updated my answer. It will work as long as cat is any `number`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see this https://eval.in/125432

```
$result = preg_replace ("/\?qa=ask&cat=\d+\//","",$url);

echo $result;
```

Comment: But he says `cat=` is vary.so `cat` could be any number.

Answer (score 0):

If it is always going to be `/?qa=ask&cat=2/` use `str_replace()`. If it is going to be by position (e.g. after the question mark and before the the next slash) that is a different matter.

Answer (score 0):

This is the pattern.

```
$pattern = "?qa=ask&cat=2/";
```

Here's the documentation. http://www.php.net/preg_replace

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you find `/?`, replace all until the next `/` is found:

```
preg_replace('~/?[^/]+/~', '/', $str);
```